# xinetd starts too early

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, upstart, xinetd

When xinetd starts when the server boots, it complains that the IP sepecified in one of the service descriptions isn't available.

My IP for eth0 is not configured in /etc/network/interfaces, but in the NetworkManager and I'd like to keep it that way if possible at all.

How can I make xinetd wait until the network interface is ready ?

In /etc/init/xinitd.conf there is a line `start on runlevel [2345]`.
I changed that to `start on (net-device-up and runlevel [2345])` but that still doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `net-device-up` in /etc/init/xinitd.conf is actually the right approach, but by default, the event fires if any network device (including the loopback device) is ready.

The full solution is to either specify that a specific network device needs to be up `net-device-up IFACE=eth0` or that any network device other than localhost must be up (`net-device-up IFACE!=lo)`.